# How to load a page after downloading without first saving it to a file

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, textbox

I'd like to parse the following in a webpage:

```
<h1 class="eTitle">bla bla bla v1.0</h1>
```

I want to display "bla bla bla v.1.0" in a textbox that I created using WPF. My code is the followind, but it display nothing in the textbox when I click the button.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
           webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
           webClient.DownloadFile("http://blablabla.com", "blabla.htm");

        HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmldoc.Load("blabla.htm");
        var titlenode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("blabla");

        textbox1.Text = "" + titlenode;
    }
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Actually I'm saving the page into a .htm file and reading from it. Can I avoid doing this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're XPath expression to get the node is not correct.

If you want to get single `h1` node use this

```
var titlenode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1");
```

If you want to get single `h1` with title `eTitle` node use this

```
var titlenode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@title = 'eTitle']");
```

For more see this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).

Then you have to access the node value and display it.

Comment: How can I access its value and display it?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid downloading the file, you can use `webClient.DownloadString("http://blablabla.com/blabla.htm");`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an `HttpWebRequest` to pull the `html` file itself?

Source: [Get html source of web page using HttpWebRequest class](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/994.html)

```
private string getHtml(string url)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url)) { return; }
    // Create Web Request
    HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    // Set GET method
    myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    // Get a response
    HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    // Open a Stream to read the response
    StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
    // Create a string to store the response
    string myPageSource = string.Empty;
    myPageSource= myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
    // Close the stream
    myWebResponse.Close();
    // Return the string
    return myPageSource;
}
```

Then using Google homepage as an example, you call `string htmlPage = getHtml("http://www.google.ca");`